# openswan IPSEC site to site randomly disconnects on debian server

Tags: ipsec, debian-wheezy, site-to-site-vpn, openswan

goodmorning my friends,
this is my situation:
I have two debian servers with static IP connected through a site to site VPN OPENSWAN, everything works like a charm, I can ping the entire lan from any workstations and transfer performance is very good. But what happens is that randomly(it can be 2 times in a day or one in 2 weeks) the VPN goes down. If I launch /etc/init.d/ipsec status I got that the tunnel is up but VPN is not working. Only solution is to launch /etc/init.d/ipsec restart or on some cases I need to reboot the routers. Anyone have some suggestions? or at last I just want to got a log somewhere but I can't find anything useful!

local ip server left is 192.168.0.100/24 and right is 192.168.1.100/24

for my privacy public ip server left is 111.222.333.555 and right is 111.222.333.444

this is my ipsec.conf on left

```
config setup
        #dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
        #forwardcontrol=yes
        nat_traversal=yes
        protostack=netkey
        #virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10
        # Use this to log to a file, or disable logging on embedded systems (like openwrt)
        #plutostderrlog=/dev/null
        #oe=off
        interfaces=%defaultroute
        #klipsdebug=all
        plutodebug=all
conn tunnel
        left=192.168.0.100 <-- left local ip
        leftid=@server1.mydomain.it
        leftrsasigkey=#####################################
        leftsubnet=192.168.0.0/24
        leftsourceip=192.168.0.100
        right=111.222.333.444 <-- right static ip
        rightid=@server2.mydomain.it
        rightrsasigkey=#####################################
        rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
        rightsourceip=192.168.1.100
        auto=start
```

and this is my ipsec.conf on right

```
config setup
        #dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
        #forwardcontrol=yes
        nat_traversal=yes
        protostack=netkey
        #virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10
        # Use this to log to a file, or disable logging on embedded systems (like openwrt)
        #plutostderrlog=/dev/null
        #oe=off
        interfaces=%defaultroute
        #klipsdebug=all
        plutodebug=all
conn tunnel
        left=111.222.333.555 <-- left static ip
        leftid=@server1.mydomain.it
        leftrsasigkey=#####################################
        leftsubnet=192.168.0.0/24
        leftsourceip=192.168.0.100
        right=192.168.1.100 <-- right local ip
        rightid=@server2.mydomain.it
        rightrsasigkey=#####################################
        rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
        rightsourceip=192.168.1.100
        auto=start
```

debian is 7 and openswan is last version Openswan U2.6.37/K3.2.0-4-amd64

ipsec verify doesn't give me errors
many thanks